# Почему полнотекстовый поиск mySQL сильно нагружает процессор?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Ubuntu 16.04. 32 ядра, 128гб RAM.
Таблица с товарами содержит 30млн записей (~30ГБ):

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`id` INT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
`model` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',    
`vendor` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
...
FULLTEXT INDEX `ftxt` (`name`, `model`, `vendor`)
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Запросы по первичному ключу вида

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id>2000000 AND id<=2000010 LIMIT 10;
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (20345234,4356352,35737,...) LIMIT 10;
```

выполняются молниеносно и даже при большом одновременном количестве запросов выполняются мгновенно, а процессор практически простаивает.

А вот запросы по полнотекстовому индексу, например

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(`name`,`model`,`vendor`) AGAINST('samsung galaxy S10' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10;
```

работают от 0.5 до 1 сек каждый, даже при небольшом количестве потоков запросов.
При этом сильно нагружают ядра процессора.

**Вопрос:** Пожалуйста, объясните мне, почему полнотекстовый поиск (несмотря на построенный индекс и то, что со временем база целиком подгружается в память сервера) сильно грузит процессор и работает медленно?

*То, что база спустя некоторое время полностью находится в памяти, вижу по утилите iotop - чтение с "диска" практически нулевое.

В данном случае меня интересует именно стандартный полнотекстовый поиск mySQL. Про Shpinx и прочее - отдельный разговор.

Как работает полнотекстовый поиск в mysql? Как он ищет по fulltext-индексу?
Можно ли как-то оптимизировать, ускорить поиск и снизить нагрузку на процессор?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно ваши подобные запросы посмотреть через команду `EXPLAIN`, там будет указано как будет выполняться тот или иной запрос

Например:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(`name`,`model`,`vendor`) AGAINST('samsung galaxy S10' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10;
```

Подробнее можно узнать [здесь](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/EXPLAIN.html)

Скорей всего у вас очень много записей в столбце `vendor` содержащее `samsung`, и у вас выбирается огромное количество записей потом только из них берется 10 штук

Comment: Присоединюсь к ответу, подумайте о нормализации бд, возможно столбцы name  и vendor стоит вынести в отдельную таблицу или таблицы. + Желательно не допускать ситуации, когда в столбце может быть NULL, потому что однажды программист может легко наступить на грабли, когда после запроса получит NULL и будет, например, на него что-то делить https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/484188/